# Merging columns and removing NA

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
A<- c(NA, 1, 2, NA, 3, NA)
R<- c(2, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1)
C<- c(rep ("B",3), rep ("D", 3))
data1<-data.frame (A,R,C)
data1
```

And I wan to merge column A and R, to have a data frame like `data2`

```
AR<- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1)
C<- c(rep ("B",3), rep ("D", 3))
data2<-data.frame (AR,C)
data2
```

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: You need some rules for how you want to merge the columns. E.g., what happens if both "A" and "R" have different values (not NA)?

Comment: About removing NA is quite common question and searching here in StackOverflow should provide enough information

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider what happens if "A" and "R" have different values, but this should work:

```
data2 <- with(data1, data.frame(AR=ifelse(is.na(A), R, A), C=C))
```

Comment: Thanks! In the case of different values what should I do to prioritize information from one column (lets say A)? Many thanks!

Comment: The way this is written, it should do what you want. The `ifelse` statement says "if A is NA then get R, otherwise keep A."